# Screen shot is not attached to allure report running with testNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng, allure

I tried of following code for attaching screen shot to Allure report and nothing works.

```
@Attachment(value = "{0}", type = "image/png")
public byte[] makeScreenshotOnFailure(String fail, WebDriver driver) {
    return ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
}

 public byte[] makeScreenshot(String path) throws IOException {
 Path content = Paths.get(path);
 try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(content)) {
 Allure.addAttachment("My attachment", is); }
return null;
 }

@Attachment(value = "{0}", type = "image/png")
public byte[] getScreenShot(String name, WebDriver driver)
{
    ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot s = new AShot().takeScreenshot(driver);

    try
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(s.getImage(), "png", stream);
        stream.flush();
        byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
        stream.close();
        System.out.println("Get screen shot method");
        return image;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me in this? If possible please share the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option:

```
@Attachment(type = "image/png")
public byte[] takeScreenshot() {
System.out.println("taking screenshot");
return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
}
```

If it doesn't work add more information about your pom.xml and the dependencies.

pom dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
        <version>${allure-maven.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>${allure-testng.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-junit4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${allure-junit4.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I use testNG but I have to add the Junit4 dependency.

Comment: Still it is not working. Is there any way to share pom file here

Comment: You can edit your question and add the relevant allure dependencies. I edit my answer to add the proper dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven, maybe the problem is related to **-javaagent** . for features like **attachment** and **steps** you have to specify **-javaagent**. you can find more explanation in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25139186/5436436)